# Why does significance change due to switching reference categories in dummy-coded multiple regression within R?

Tags: r, regression, dummy-variable, significance

I have a problem with dummy-coded multiple regression in R. I realised that when I switch reference categories under certain circumstances - that I can't specify yet - the result changes. So effects that haven't been significant become significant suddenly and the other way round although nothing else has been changed except from which category I choose as reference.

In my opinion the effects shouldn't change in that scenario because substantially the question stays the same. In some examples I tried the effects stay the same but in others they changed and I can't tell yet what leads to that difference. I've already read through a lot of books about regression analysis and several platforms but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: You'll need to provide some example data and the code you're using.  Most likely you're either looking at p-values for a test of a difference between two levels of a multi-level factor or possibly you are looking at the type I tests and changed some stuff around. It's hard to say without seeing code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This belongs on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com); you can delete and re-post yourself, or wait for it to get closed & migrated ...